# Is Dr. Pepper Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification

Is [Dr. Pepper](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/souleater/images/1/1c/Dr._Pepper_can.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141121011002), a soft-drink with particular popularity in Texas, kosher? What about the [vintage version](http://www.bevreview.com/wp-content/image_drpepper_with_imperialsugar1.jpg) that is sweetened with sugar as opposed to artificial sweeteners? There is no hechsher on the box or can, but that might be a thing subject to locality as I live in a place with a very low Jewish population, let alone a Rabbinical authority.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. "What have I tried?"

Comment: Well did you for example google "is doctor pepper kosher". That would be a good first step. If you have, you could mention this in the question so others don't duplicate your effort. If you haven't, consider doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CRC](http://www.crcweb.org/beverage_list.php) the following flavours are kosher:

> Original
>
> Berries and Cream
>
> Cherry
>
> Cherry Vanilla
>
> Chocolate Cherry
>
> Heritage
>
> Red Fusion
>
> Ten
>
> Vanilla Float

The [Heritage](http://www.bevreview.com/2010/01/13/heritage-dr-pepper/) listed (which uses real sugar) is the same as the "vintage" which you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. The Heritage variety is the same, as I have seen these in grocery stores, convenience stores, etc.

Comment: You are very welcome. (BTW I didn't find any references referring to it as "vintage" are you sure it isn't just called 'heritage'?)

Comment: I didn't know exactly what is was called so I just said "vintage," as the soda mimics the way Dr. Pepper used to be made when it first came out in 1885.

Comment: There was a period of about 2-3 years when Doctor Peppper was considered dairy. One of the ingredients was lactic acid. I don't think that their are using this any longer, but, since you mentioned "vintage" you should check for that ingredient.